# Cannot Locate GPU Quota Increase for Google Cloud Account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-dl-platform, gae-quotas

I am currently trying to increase the GPU quota for Google Cloud Platform. However, I am unable to search Google Compute Engine API for increasing the GPU quota.

No option comes up when I search for "Compute Engine API" or "GPU All Regions"

Has the format of the search criteria been changed?
Previous tutorials are deprecated.

[image]

Comment: Unclear. See the documentation [GPU quota](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#gpu_quota). Do you have Compute Engine API enabled in the project? I'm unable to repro your issue. If you clear the filter and start with "gpu", you should see the 6 GPU metrics listed.

Comment: My bad. I just activated the Compute Engine API, and can now see the 6 GPU metrics listed. However, I am still recieving the message, "No quotas are available with the given options" for the increase requests tab.

Comment: EDIT: Resolved the error message. Select the checkbox for the corresponding Compute Engine API service, then click "Edit Quota" on the upper right of the window.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Sorry for the late answer!
The UX is a little confusing but the filter works fine.

One way of finding the GPUs: you can directly click on the filter then select "name" and start typing "GPU" then some suggestions will popup..

hope this helps